# Unable to run (gulp serve) Google Polymer Starter Kit v1.1.0 on Windows

Tags: node.js, gulp, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I need help please!

I have been able to effortlessly install and run all previous versions of the PSK. I have spent hours now trying to get 1.1.0 to run in my environment. I have done everything I can think of. From googling the error to reviewing all current issues with this version here. Any of the suggested fixes dont work for me.

I have made no code changes and I am running CMD as the Admin.

When I grab a fresh copy of the repository and do the NPM & Bower installs, then run "gulp serve" I get the following error no matter what:

```
C:\FrontEnd\polymer-starter-kit>gulp serve
[09:45:33] Using gulpfile C:\FrontEnd\polymer-starter-kit\gulpfile.js
[09:45:33] Starting 'styles'...
[09:45:33] Starting 'elements'...
[09:45:33] Starting 'images'...
[09:45:33] Finished 'elements' after 249 ms
[09:45:33] styles all files 98 B
[09:45:33] Finished 'styles' after 590 ms
[09:45:34] images all files 35.41 kB
[09:45:34] Finished 'images' after 357 ms
[09:45:34] Starting 'serve'...
[09:45:34] Finished 'serve' after 73 ms
[PSK] Access URLs:
 ------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:5000
External: http://xxx.xxx.x.x:5000
 ------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://xxx.xxx.x.x:3001
 ------------------------------------
[PSK] Serving files from: .tmp
[PSK] Serving files from: app
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:429:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:343:17)
```

**My Environment:**

- All Required Prerequisites
- Windows 10
- Node.js v4.1.1
- NPM v3.3.4
- Bower v1.5.3

I am also not sure how to get a more detailed stack trace.

What should I do?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try using the generator https://github.com/yeoman/generator-polymer

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I needed to add **C:\Windows\System32** to my PATH vars. So strange. When I did that everything work like a charm.